# New iPhone and Provisioning Problems

Tags: iphone, xcode, provisioning

I just got a new iPhone because my old one broke, and when I tried to run my app on the new iPhone I got this message:

Provisioning profile 'iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *' specifies the Application Identifier '*' which doesn't match the current setting...

I'm pretty sure I haven't messed with any build settings, but is there any way to have the old provisioning profile for my new phone and delete it for the old one?

Thanks in advanced,

Cheers,
Adam

Answer (score 1):

Did you add your new device's UDID to the list of Devices through you apple account here: https://developer.apple.com  then Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles.  Once you add your device your iOS Team Provisioning Profile should automatically update with the new device.

Then in your xCode Organizer choose "Devices" and select refresh at the bottom.  This will retrieve your updated Team Provisioning Profile.

After that I would just double check under Project -> Build Settings -> Code Signing to ensure that the updated Provisioning Profile is selected.

Comment: Maybe start fresh by deleting profile from phone in your Phone's Settings?  Maybe if the old provisioning profile is on there it might be looking at the wrong one.  Other than that I would be out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Delete Provisioning Profile: Setting -> General -> Provisioning Profiles

And one important step for debug on new device: Xcode -> Organizer ->  Devices -> your new device -> Use for Development.

Answer (score 0):

1) add the UDID of your new iPhone to the provisioning profile you using.

2) download the provisioning profile again and drag and drop it to the xCode.

3) if it's not working then restart the xCode and try the same process again